# php unzipping huge files

Tags: php, file, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a huge file (400+M compressed  well over 4G unzipped) using php zip archive.  I'm only unzipping one csv file in the zipped file..  the file I am interested in, unzipped, is over 4G.. I get as far as 3 records from the end of the file and the process takes off into lala land.. I mean the process simply goes on.. no output.. no errors no looping it just goes on...  I haven't a clue as to what its doing.. my code is simple:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) 
{
   $num = $zip->numFiles;
   for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
   {
      $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
  // if its the file I want then...
      $content = '';
  // my output file  .. yes I've already checked to make sure the dir exists
      $unzipped = fopen($dir ."/2" . $filename  , 'wb');         
      $fp = $zip->getStream($filename);
      if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");
      while (!feof($fp))
      {
    $chunkSize = 10240;
    $contents = fread($fp, $chunkSize);
        $fwrite = fwrite($unzipped, $contents);
      }
      fclose($fp);
      fclose($unzipped);
    }

    $zip->close();
    fclose($filename);

}
```

I've removed the write statements that go to another file to track progress.  I get most of the file out.. (as I said 3 records short of the entire file)... but the process seems to go off somewhere..  it gets happens on the fread I just can't figure out what is happening..  It hasn't reached the eof.. the source is intact (checked with is_source($fp) just before the fread.. it throws no errors.. closing the browser doesn't stop it.. can't even stop apache.. have to shut down to end it...

any ideas??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a bug to be honest(in php).

you might want to try outputting calls to [memory_get_usage](http://www.php.net/memory_get_usage)() to help you debug. But, also, see [stream_copy_to_stream](http://www.php.net/stream_copy_to_stream)() because you can get rid of all that looping cruft. It might also be intresteting to keep a running total of bytes written to see if the number where things go awry look suspicious.

Comment: According to someone at the documentation page the function appears to use quite a bit of memory on its own. So if that is true and memory is the issue here, this might not be the solution.

Comment: Hi Chris, tried it with interesting results, it didn't copy the entire file, but it didn't go off into lala land either, which kind of leads me to believe that the first problem may be the initial zip stream.. It may not be getting everything..  but that's a different question and I need to so some research before posting.. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark, but try increasing the amount of memory the script can allocate. I've had similar problems when using the gzip functions and I had to make this change.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Comment: Hi Nick,  Thanks for the suggestion, tried it but it made no dif..  but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = '/media/file.gz';

$unzipped_content = '';   
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
while ($zip_file = gzread($zd, 10000000)){
    $unzipped_content.= $zip_file;
}
gzclose($zd);

echo $unzipped_content;
```